# How to exclude a gem from bundle install even though it's in Gemfile.lock?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I am working on setting up a new development environment and I realized that I am facing a minor roadblock. I am using Sidekiq Pro in production, but in development I am wanting to avoid it to prevent spreading the license across other developers.

To do so, in my `Gemfile` I have the following:

```
group :production do 
  source "https://gems.contribsys.com/" do
    gem "sidekiq-pro"
  end
end
```

However, this *does* exist in my `Gemfile.lock` file:

```
    sidekiq-pro (5.2.1)
      connection_pool (>= 2.2.3)
      sidekiq (>= 6.1.0)
```

So when I'm calling `bundle install` from within a docker build, how do I prevent `bundle install` from trying to use the `sidekiq-pro` gem? The problem is that it errors out because of authentication being required:

```
Step 6/12 : RUN bundle install --without production
 ---> Running in 0642e1440b33
The dependency tzinfo-data (>= 0) will be unused by any of the platforms Bundler is installing for. Bundler is installing for ruby but the dependency is only for x86-mingw32, x86-mswin32, x64-mingw32, java. To add those platforms to the bundle, run `bundle lock --add-platform x86-mingw32 x86-mswin32 x64-mingw32 java`.
Authentication is required for gems.contribsys.com.
Please supply credentials for this source. You can do this by running:
 bundle config gems.contribsys.com username:password
The command '/bin/sh -c bundle install --without production' returned a non-zero code: 17
ERROR: Service 'app' failed to build
```

As you can see, I have specified `--without production` in the `bundle install` arguments, but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative (though not so elegant) to the --without option is another gem called `bundle-only`. It uses the CLI and it can `bundle install` a specific environment. A good thing is that this gem will not occupy space in your `Gemfile.lock`.

Gem repo [here](https://github.com/MOZGIII/bundle-only)

Run:

- gem install bundle-only
- bundle-only production